# How to repair Windows 7 on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bsod

I have a Windows 7 VirtualBox guest installed on my Windows 7 host machine and I cannot boot into it now.

A blue screen is followed by a failed auto boot-repair effort.

Is there a way to repair install the Windows 7 VirtualBox without losing my non-OS data?

Answer (score 1):

> A blue screen is followed by a failed auto boot-repair effort.

Which is the blue screen error code you see?. To have a chance of repair first thing you should do is search for its meaning and/or a known resolution about that specific error code on Google/Microsoft.

> Is there a way to repair install the Windows 7 VirtualBox without
>   losing my non-OS data?

To recover your files instead of trying to repair the boot step failure, one thing that probably you could do is insert an ISO containing a Windows installation to perform a reinstallation of your OS in the virtual machine (ensure in BIOS that the CD-Rom boots before the HDD), this way your files from the corrupted installation will be kept in a new folder named "**C:\Windows.old**".

To do a clean installation and also preserve your current files in "**C:\Windows.old**", remember to select the "**Custom**" install mode:

[image]